# How can values in a yaml script be dynamically generated from the project information in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I would like to be able to draw on the repository information to do this, but I cannot find any guidance with regard to how I might do it.

Comment: It would be easier to help, if you explain what exactly do you mean by "project information". You can fetch a lot of things from GitLab API - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way to access the data I was looking for was through the "pre-packaged" environment variables present in gitlab-ci/cd.